# Coded UI project Causing Entity Framework ModelValidationException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, interface, coded-ui-tests

I am having a problem wherein Coded UI projects are throwing ModelValidationException on data access, but other projects (Unit Tests, Web, Console, WinForm) do not.

My underlying database has several sets of Code-First entities that have similar properties for different states. Roughly, think a quote and a sales record. These records are split up into different tables based on the state of a business transaction, because of reasons I have no control or input over.

So I have a set of entities with common fields and some repetition:

```
public class QuoteMoney
{
     Decimal Amount { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class SaleMoney
{
     Decimal Amount { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class Quote
{
    List<QuoteMoney> QuoteMonies { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class Sale
{
    List<SaleMoney> SaleMonies { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}
```

Due to the commonality, I have a set of classes that implement mapping into the Entity Framework classes, using generics and interfaces for the common elements. I have these interfaces also using generic to force type integrity, so that a Quote can't have SaleMoney and so forth. i.e.:

```
public Interface IContainer<GContainer, GMoney>
    where GContainer : IContainer<GContainer, GMoney>
    where GMoney : IMoney<GContainer, GMoney>
{
    List<GMoney> Monies { get; set; }
}

public Interface IMoney<GContainer, GMoney>
    where GContainer : IContainer<GContainer, GMoney>
    where GMoney : IMoney<GContainer, GMoney>
{
     Decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that to keep a generic name on the interface, the result has a common name, but the tables have specific collection names. We have existing code that I don't want to impact, so the solution becomes:

```
public class QuoteMoney : IMoney<Quote, QuoteMoney>
{
     Decimal Amount { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     Decimal IMoney<Quote, QuoteMoney>.Amount { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class SaleMoney : IMoney<Sale, SaleMoney>
{
     Decimal Amount { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     Decimal IMoney<Sale, SaleMoney>.Amount { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class Quote : IContainer<Quote, QuoteMoney>
{
    List<QuoteMoney> QuoteMonies { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     List<QuoteMoney> IContainer<Quote, QuoteMoney>.Monies { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}

public class Sale : IContainer<Sale, SaleMoney>
{
    List<SaleMoney> SaleMonies { get; set; }

     [NotMapped]
     List<SaleMoney> IContainer<Sale, SaleMoney>.Monies { get; set; }
     //...etc.
}
```

This pattern is extended out to several different collections, with about 7 generic types. This is all well and good in all production and test code. Everything works, until I start writing Coded UI tests. I want to insert a dummy record, then delete it and test that this works.

When I try to do the insertion in a coded UI test (insert the record, spin up the application, then delete), I am getting a ModelValidationException, with two errors for each of the interface properties in the entire model (redacted for brevity):

```
[Long Namespace].IQuote<[Long Namespace].Quote, [Long Namespace].QuoteMoney>, etc.>.Monies : Name: The specified name must not be longer than 480 characters: '[repeated name]'
[Long Namespace].IQuote<[Long Namespace].Quote, [Long Namespace].QuoteMoney>, etc.>.Monies : Name: The specified name is not allowed: '[repeated name]'
```

The internal call stack is:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmModel.Validate()
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

This recurs for each type of property on each type inheriting from a generic interface in the entire model. This only occurs in Coded UI projects, not on any other project type.

Is there some known conflict between Coded UI and Entity Framework?

**EDIT**: added in Stack trace, minor text corrections

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI is an automated black box testing tool, it works in the client browser and it's got nothing to do with EF which is on the server side.

Its the data you're putting in the system, not the Coded UI, at least apparently.
We can see in your snippet that there's a string length error and a duplication error as well.

Please try to reduce the length of the string you're supplying through CUI and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, you would think that would be exactly the case. However, the problem is that in a Coded UI project (any coded UI project, even a freshly created one) the EDM model is going through validation that should not be occurring. The fields with offending names are **explicitly excluded**; in other project execution paths that exclusion is honored. In a Coded UI project, that exclusion is not honored in the EDM model validation, which is obviously confusing. Additionally, the EF is being explicitly called from Coded UI methods, not a server side execution. There isn't even a server in this case.

Comment: sounds more complicated than my expectation. I wish I could help but can't think of anything. Can wish best of luck only :D

Answer (score 0):

Erik, as Naeem said in general CodedUI is a sort of black box solution. I think I understand at a high level what you're trying to do - Insert a record into the DB, ensure that it appears in the application's UI through CodedUI, then delete it. As far as I know, I have not encountered any CodedUI-specific incompatibilities or wrinkles regarding EF.

My gut feeling would be that you notice a difference between your unit testing projects and your CodedUI ones. Perhaps in the references.

Another suggestion would be to have the CodedUI project call data setup methods that exist in another project. Ideally your service/unit tests may need similar data setup.

I'll admit I'm rusty in EF, but what I am unsure about is how you're inserting these records with no validation as you suggest in your comment.